Can't run TypeOrm migrations with webpack: MODULE_NOT_FOUND
I have node.js app built with webpack. I am following this FAQ
My webpack config has one entrypoint for the migrator script, and multiple entrypoints for migration files:
const commonConfig = require('./webpack.config.common');
const path = require('path');
const glob = require('glob');

const migrations = glob
  .sync(path.resolve('src/database/migrations/tenanted/*{.ts,.js}'))
  .reduce((entries, filename) => {
    const migrationName = path.basename(filename, '.ts');
    return Object.assign({}, entries, {
      ['migrations/tenanted/' + migrationName]: filename
    });
  }, {});

module.exports = {
  ...commonConfig,
  entry: {
    'migrator/lambda': './src/database/migrations/migrator-lambda.ts',
    ...migrations
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    clean: true
  },
  optimization: {
    minimize: false
  }
};


When I try to perform the migration, it throws an error:
Error: Cannot find module '...path\dist\migrations\tenanted\1720649022000-MigrationName.js'
    at webpackEmptyContext ...path\lambda.js:156879:10)
    at tryToRequire ...path\lambda.js:155742:82)
    at importOrRequireFile ...path\lambda.js:155756:24)
    at async ...path\lambda.js:155691:41
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async importClassesFromDirectories ...path\lambda.js:155694:18)
    at async ConnectionMetadataBuilder.buildMigrations ...path\lambda.js:91216:17)
    at async DataSource.buildMetadatas ...path\lambda.js:92167:28)
    at async DataSource.initialize ...path\lambda.js:91839:13)
    at async getTenantConnection ...path\lambda.js:90369:5) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}

However, the file location is correct. And the migration class is correctly exported there.
Webpack can't dynamically load it for some reason.
Any idea how to fix it?
